# Is it possible to wipe data from ADB without turning on USB debugging?

Tags: adb, screen, broken-screen

I'm on manjaro Linux. A friend of mine broke the screen of his note 3, it's working, the screen stays black though.

He wants to get all his data from it and format it, wipe everything, he's not going to fix it.

The back up part is easy, I plug it into my computer and take everything. But is it possible to format it without turning on the USB debugging? I bet the USB debugging on his phone is turned off and I can't turn it on without being able to see anything on his phone. So as far as I know I can't use ABD, can I?

Comment: Without enabling *USB debugging* I doubt the `adbd` (ADB daemon) is running, so I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @GiantTree I'm going to try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7Z_r0Z0CEo

Comment: Could download a custom recovery for the device and flash it via odin. I think Clockwork mod has adb built into it. Then you can run the commands that way... In theory. Lol

Comment: @jer3my without usb debugging enabled? AFAIK odin won't work if usb debugging ain't enabled

Comment: @Lynob. As far as I know, odin doesn't require USB debugging. It doesn't need it when the phone is in download mode.

Comment: @jer3my good idea, please leave an answer, I'll vote it up now and accept it on monday if it works, cause monday I'll try to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could try downloading a custom recovery, such as Clockworkmod for the device and flash it via odin. I think Clockwork mod has adb shell built into it. Then you can run the commands that way. And as far as I know, odin doesn't require USB debugging. It doesn't need it when the phone is in download mode.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge if you do not have USB debugging ADB is not running and any tools that rely on ADB will fail to work.

Answer (score 1):

since i'm not able to comment, i'll make an answer. i've been in this exact spot with this device before. you won't be able to flash the recovery w/o  triggering knox and voiding the warranty. if that's not a concern, you should be in the clear. keep in mind, you could lose the data at any point in the process. samsung has notoriously unreliable USB controllers and if they decided to stop working, the data is probably lost. don't use odin, use heimdall. here's a guide:

https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2014/05/18/recovering-photos-and-data-from-a-keylocked-android-phone/